# How do I create/edit a user profile for a Stream react-native app?

Tags: getstream-io

Is there a builtin UI component in the Stream for react-native library to edit a user's profile?

I have the feeds and activities working and integrated with my user id and token server side api, but users obviously show up as the default "Unknown" with no photo. I don't have profile storage yet in this new application so I'm wondering if there is a quick drop-in for a Profile screen and editing of that profile or if I have to build that and add the metadata to the stream User API.

Answer (score 1):

There is no profile component, but you can access the information and create your own.

Firstly, set the profileImage field of the user in getstream like so (example shown server side but you can use do client side with a token):

```
const client = stream.connect('xxx', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxx');
let clientData = await client.user(userId).get();

if (!clientData.data) return null;
  
clientData.data.profileImage = 'https://cdn.com/profile.png';
await client.user(context.params.userId).update(clientData.data);
```

Then you can access it like so on client: (example shows feed with a custom header.):

```
const CustomActivity = (props) => {
    return  <Activity {...props} 
    Header={
      <View style={styles.avatarView}>
            <Avatar 
              source={props.activity.actor.data.profileImage}
              size={36}
              noShadow
            />
            <View style={styles.actorView}>
              <Text style={styles.actorName}>{props.activity.actor.data.name}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.metaData}>{formatRelative(new Date(props.activity.time), new Date())}</Text>
            </View>
      </View>
    }>
      </Activity>

        <StreamApp apiKey={STREAM_API_KEY} appId={STREAM_APP_ID} token={user.activity.token}>
          <FlatFeed feedGroup="timeline" notify  Activity={CustomActivity} />
        </StreamApp>
```